# Don't know how to write complex Mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here is the schema used to display current tournaments in one country:

```
var TournamentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  location: String,
  googlelink: String,
  description: String,
  format: String,
  date: Date
  closedate:Date
  type:String

});
```

The webpage also has filters like in ecommerce sites. If suppose I get one query from url like:
https://www.example.com/format=5v5%7v7&&location=hyd&&ahmedabad

I need to make query for tournaments which are 5v5 or 7v7 format and which are in Hyd and Ahmedabad.

I need to write generalised query as I don't know about number of places and format.

I don't know how to do this. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You can use query like this `Tournament.find().where('location').in(['Hyd', 'Ahmedabad']).where('format').or(['5v5','7v7']).exec(function(err,results){...});`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a query I wrote that uses mongoose $or.

```
Event.find( { $or: [{ joiners:   req.user._id  },  { creator: req.user._id}]  }  )  
.populate('creator')

.exec(function(err, goevent){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        res.json(goevent)
    }
})
```

Basically in your query param {} you can pass in something like this:

```
{ $or: [ { query: one}, {query: two} ] }
```

Like so:

```
Model.find({ $or: [ { query: one}, {query: two} ] }, function(err, data){
  //err & success handlers
}
```

Once you figure that out, you can use a bunch of other logical operators as well, like `$and`.

if the object you are querying is nested you just do `'some.property'` (use string syntax when accessing objects with dot notation)